# Jest mocking an ES6 class to be used by the class being tested

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to create a mocked js class in jest, this class is used to get/put data to a server that is not available during testing. So I've been trying to create a mocked class that will pass data when called, below are the classes

data-service-controller.js

```
class DataServiceController {
  constructor() {
    this._model = DataServiceModel;
  }

  getUser(id){
    return $.get('some-url');
  }

}

export default new DataServiceController();
```

user-controller.js

```
import DataServiceController from '...';

class UserController {
  constructor() {
    this.userId = '';
  }

  checkUserPermissions(id) {
    DataServiceController.getUser(id).then((resp) => { ... });
  }
}
export default new UserController();
```

user-controller.test.js

```
import UserController from "./user-controller.js";

describe("A utility class for user", () => {
    describe("check permissions", () => {
        it("should check the users permissions", () => {
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

I'm trying to mock the DataServiceController but having issues and haven't found any good example of how to mock the namespace so that the `UserController` will use the mocked DataServiceController and I can use the mock to pass values.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ES6 Class Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#the-4-ways-to-create-an-es6-class-mock) on the jest docs. A lot of good information and examples, you may be able get by with just an automatic mock without having to define a manual mock. Also look at [Mocking Modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) since you are exporting singleton instances not classes.

Jest mocks are hoisted, so you can mock a dependency within the test, without having to worry about putting it before your import.

Example:

```js
import UserController from "./user-controller.js";
import DataServiceController from './path/to/DataServiceController';

jest.mock('./path/to/DataServiceController');

describe("A utility class for user", () => {
    describe("check permissions", () => {
        it("should check the users permissions", () => {
           DataServiceController.getUser.mockResolvedValue({...});
           return UserController.checkUserPermissions(123).then(() => {
             //Make assertions that your mock resolved value is being used
           });
        });
    });
});
```

This is a helpful repository about [how mocks work.](https://github.com/kentcdodds/how-jest-mocking-works) which addresses hoisting.